Docker with Elastic Beanstalk Error: GET http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O_vbJn8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
I am very new to Docker and AWS, and for my chess project I have a React/Node application that uses socket.io and Docker and I want to deploy everything onto AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I've finished the docker containerization and everything works locally, but when I attempt to access the application on beanstalk, while the program runs, the socket connection does not. I am getting this polling error in my dev console:
enter image description here
Which consistently appears as I assume it is polling. Could anyone take a look?
Here is my server.js:
const express = require('express');
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const app = express(); // initialize express
const server = http.createServer(app); // HTTP server created
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080 // set port to value received from environment variable or 8080 if null
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*", // Update this to your frontend's origin
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "HEAD"],
        credentials: true
    }
});

const cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Parses JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());
// Serve static files from the react app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public')));
// all other requests point to the index.html file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/public', 'index.html'));
});

Socket.js:
import { io } from "socket.io-client"; // import connection function

const socket = io(); // initialize websocket connection on port 8080

export default socket;

Dockerrun.aws.json:
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "767397913162.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1v1chess:latest",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": 8080,
            "HostPort": 8080
        }
    ]
}

Some more things:

I also wrote a loadbalancer.conf and websockets.conf, but I'm not sure if they are even needed. Let me know if you need me to upload those as well.
I use ECR and I push the docker image there, and I deploy and upload the dockerrun.aws.json file to beanstalk.
I am using an application load balancer.

I disabled this chrome flag: chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests and everything worked for a night. The day after, it wasn't working again, even with the flag off.

If you using a container, use ECS
